# What is preventing my disk from spindown?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, hdparm

I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 installed on my laptop on SSD, and I also have a HDD for my large files. I want my hard disk to go to standby mode and spindown after 10 minutes. so I set it with `hdparm` with this command:

```
hdparm -S 129 -B 128 /dev/sda
```

Everything is alright when I set spindown `-S` and APM `-B` values less (actually 10 minutes) but it seems something is accessing my disk every 10 minutes (I can exactly hear it from the noise!) But that thing doesn't do anything when the disk has gone to standby. So disk can't go to standby when the `hdparm` value is larger than this.

I also stopped `smartmontools` service to be sure it's not doing this (though, it checks disk every 30 minutes, unless disk is on standby)

How can I find what is preventing my disk to spindown?

My HDD model number is:     TOSHIBA MQ04ABF100

Comment: Possible reasons: 1) A swap partition on /dev/sda. 2) Some harddisks (Western Digital? I forgot) have some internal timer that causes them to spin up again, IIRC you need a special tool to disable that timer. 3) Something that writes logs on /dev/sda.

Comment: I don't have swap partition on this drive, and also it's not Western digital.

Comment: I found something [here] (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks) (I was actually searching for something related to disk  that repeats every 10 min!) It's about **Broken standby timer ** (at the end of article). Could it be a reason?

Comment: Yes, it could be a reason. Also, if you include the model number of your harddisk from `hdparm -I /dev/sda` in the question, readers can google for specific issues for this model.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep this command (from package [blktrace](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/blktrace)) running:

```
sudo btrace /dev/sda
```

It will display in realtime any process accessing `/dev/sda` (even through multiple layers of indirection like filesystem -> LVM -> cryptsetup -> partition -> disk block), so this should be easy to discover what is preventing the disk to spin down.

Comment: Thanks this command is very helpful. However blktrace package wanted to install so many dependencies (over 334 MB more used storage). To mitigate this, use sudo apt download blktrace and then sudo dpkg --force-all -i blktrace_1.2.0-5_arm64.deb resp the name of the package you've just downloaded.

Comment: @Hannes Better do this `apt-get --no-install-recommends install blktrace` (the package recommends ffmpeg & co. probably because `iowatcher` can create movies of the sampled values). So if you're missing a library apt will still fetch it (dpkg can't, it's not its role).